# How does Hibernate delete(obj) an object?

Tags: hibernate

Does it just delete whatever object has the id of the obj, or does it reference all of its properties first?

For example, say I want to delete `TransactionRequest transactionRequest` tr1 with

```
id = 25, amount = 311, client_id = 13
```

does it first make sure all of these properties check out, or does it just delete whatever `TransactionRequest` has an id of 25?

Answer (score 0):

Condition about deleting an object only you know.

If, for you is enough the `id` field, you can proceed, if you want to extend your conditions (over other fields as amount and client_id you can do it).

To delete an object, you can follow two ways (I use your `TransactionRequest` object as example):

**The first:**

Get the object by query and delete it:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select from TransactionRequest t where t.id = :yourParam");
q.setString("yourParam, "25");
TransactionRequest toDelete = (TransactionRequest)q.uniqueResult();
session.delete(toDelete);
```

**The second:**

Write a delete query

```
Query q = session.createQuery("delete from TransactionRequest where id = :yourParam");
q.setString("yourParam, "25");
q.executeUpdate();
```

**Difference between two ways:**

If you use the first way, you'll guarantee to delete your object and sets of data mapped with cascade clause

If you use the second way, you can't delete your object if you have in your object a set/list/bag mapped

Comment: one more note: all bulk operations (delete from ...) bypass interceptor and event listeners and first level cache.